# LinkedList in JavaScript, how to append changes to list?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I'm running into a referential issue with variables in JavaScript, and I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out.

I'm preparing to teach a class on data structures, and I'm reviewing the material after not looking at it for at least 10 years.

I know Linked Lists in theory, but for some reason, I'm struggling to come up with code that actually works in JavaScript (I chose JavaScript because that's what my class knows best)

This is my code:

```
let LinkedList  = {
    head: {},
    tail: {}
};

let Node = {
    data: {},
    next: {}
}

function isObjectEmpty(obj1) {
    return Object.keys(obj1).length === 0 && obj1.constructor === Object;
}

function count(node, counter) {
    if (node.next) {
        return 1 + count(node.next, counter);
    }
    return counter;
}

/**
 * Adds data to LinkedList
 * @param {LinkedList} list
 * @param {Node} data
 */
function add_node(list, data) {
    let temp = Object.assign({}, Node);
    temp.data = data;
    temp.next = {};

    if (Object.keys(list.head).length === 0) {
        list.head = temp;
        list.tail = temp;
    } else {
        list.tail.next = temp;
        list.tail = temp;
    }
    return list;
}
function insert(l, n, position) {
    if (position <= 0) {
        position = 0;
    } else {
        position = position - 1;
    }

    var list = Object.assign({}, l);
    var node = Object.assign({}, Node);
    node.data = n;

    // this only counts elements on the list.
    var elements = count(list.head, 0);

    if (position > elements) {
        return list;
    }

    var currentPosition = list.head;
    var counter = 0;

    while (!isObjectEmpty(currentPosition)) {
        if (position === counter) {
            var tmp = currentPosition;
            currentPosition = node;
            currentPosition.next = tmp.next;
            return list;
        }
        currentPosition = currentPosition.next;
        counter++;
    }

    return list;
}

// how to use the function
let songs = [
{id: '1', name: 'Kamikaze', artist: 'Eminem', releaseDate: '2018-08-31'},
{id: '2', name: 'despacito', artist: 'Luis Fonsi', releaseDate: '2018-08-31'},
{id: '3', name: 'La tortura', artist: 'Shakira', releaseDate: '2018-08-31'},
{id: '4', name: 'Roar', artist: 'Roar', releaseDate: '2018-08-31'},
 ];

let list = Object.assign({}, LinkedList);
    songs.forEach((song) => {
        add_node(list, song); // nothing special, just builds the linkedlist
     });

list = insert(list, {id: '5', name: 'Havana', artist:'who knows', releaseDate:'2018-01-01'}, 3); 
console.log(list); // new object isn't there.
```

This function is supposed to insert an element in an arbitrary position in the linked list. It kinda works. The problem is that the returned list keeps the reference to the old object before the re-association.

If you put a debugger in this block:

```
    if (position === counter) {
        var tmp = currentPosition;
        currentPosition = node;
        currentPosition.next = tmp.next;
        return list;
    }
```

You can see that I'm actually successfully inserting the new node where I want to.

But if you `console.log` the `list` structure, you'll see that the newly inserted Node is nowhere to be found.

I'm not sure where I'm failing or why the list keeps the old references and doesn't follow the new "path".

Any pointers in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those `Object.assign` calls are bogus, it doesn't clone the nested objects.

Comment: Can you please also add an example of how you would call the function?

Comment: What is `esObjetoVacio`? And shouldn't you have a `null` check there?

Comment: @Bergi I just added more code, that should be a full example reproducing the issue.

Comment: Can you try this let temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Node)); instead of let temp = Object.assign({}, Node);? for each of Object.assign. May be the object reference is messing things up.

Comment: @binariedMe I updated, but no dice. I don't think deep clone is an issue in that particular line as the Node object is empty at that point of the execution of the program.

Comment: why not use an instance of node and linked list instead of objects?

Comment: these students are too new to the language to follow prototypal inheritance on top of a brand new concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you put a debugger in this block:
>
> ```
> if (position === counter) {
>     var tmp = currentPosition;
>     currentPosition = node;
>     currentPosition.next = tmp.next;
>     return list;
> }
> ```
>
> You can see that I'm actually successfully inserting the new node
>   where I want to

No, you don't. If we drop the `tmp` and `currentPosition` assignment confusion, that bit of code is equivalent to

```
if (position === counter) {
    node.next = currentPosition.next;
    return list;
}
```

All that happens is that you are copying the tail of the list onto the new node, but you never really insert the node as the `next` of the one currently in the list. It's missing a

```
currentPosition.next = node;
```

---

A couple of other points:

- Don't use `isObjectEmpty` and empty objects to represent "no node". Use `null` instead. If for some didactic reason you don't want to introduce `null`, use a boolean `.isNode` property on the objects to distinguish a node with data from an empty one.
- Avoid `Object.assign`. Your usage is really unidiomatic. In

  ```
  let temp = Object.assign({}, Node);
  temp.data = data;
  temp.next = {};
  ```

  you are directly overwriting the values that you just copied from `Node` - better simplify to using an object literal:

  ```
  let temp = {data, next: {}};
  ```

  In `var list = Object.assign({}, l);` you don't really want to create a new object at all. You are going to mutate the passed in list, so you should just keep that. (If you wanted to make pure functions with immutable data structures, you would have to make all the nodes immutable as well, and for inserting clone the entire list until the desired position).
- If your intention for `Object.assign` was to create new objects that later might involve other properties (or methods) that you weren't going to overwrite, use factory functions instead.
- Don't `count` the list beforehand. Do the insertion in a single pass, and if you reach the end of the list before the position to inert then `return`.

```
function makeLinkedList() {
    return { head: null, tail: null };
}

function makeNode(data, next = null) {
    return { data, next };
}

function append(list, node) {
    if (list.head) {
        list.tail.next = node;
    } else {
        list.head = node;
    }
    list.tail = node;
}

function insert(list, data, position) {
    if (position < 0) throw new Error("position must be nonnegative");

    let newNode = makeNode(data);
    let prev = null, cur = list.head;
    while (cur != null && position > 0) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur.next;
        position--;
    }
    if (cur == null && position > 0) throw new Error("position must be <= list length")
    if (cur == null) {
        list.tail = newNode;
    } else {
        newNode.next = cur;
    }
    if (prev == null) {
        list.head = newNode;
    } else {
        prev.next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code review!! Your points on Object.assign make a lot of sense, I was trying to make the list immutable and write pure functions but I overlooked the other issue. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @ILikeTacos If you make an immutable list, this will greatly simplify the implementation as you don't need the `list` object any more - you can instead represent the list by its head node. You don't need the `tail` reference then. I also would recommend to use recursive `append` and `insert` functions then instead of iterative ones.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems. First, you're replacing a node, not strictly inserting. I think you want your `.next` to be the `tmp` node, not `tmp.next`.

```
currentPosition.next = tmp;
```

Second, you need to keep a reference to the node immediately before the insertion point, so that you can set its `next` value to the newly inserted node:

```
previousNode.next = node //<- node being the one you're inserting
```

that's why you're not seeing the difference in your linked list.

*Edit (putting it all together):

```
var prevNode = null;
while (!isObjectEmpty(currentPosition)) {
  if (position === counter) {
    var tmp = currentPosition;
    currentPosition = node;
    currentPosition.next = tmp;
    if (prevNode === null) list.head = currentPosition;
    else prevNode.next = currentPosition;
    return list;
  }
  prevNode = currentPosition;
  currentPosition = currentPosition.next;
  counter++;
}
```

To make it safe for inserting into the initial position, we have to have the ability to set the `list.head`. Otherwise we set the previous node's `next` property.

Comment: but where would I put the `previousNode.next`? I think I follow what you're saying, and yes I agree, `currentPosition.next` should be set to `tmp` not to `tmp.next` I'm just having trouble following the `previousNode` comment. I also thought of keeping a reference to a previous element, just wasn't sure how to incorporate it into the solution.

Comment: I added some code to show how you could have a reference to the previous node, so that you could change its `next` link to point to the new item that you're inserting.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a version without `Object.assign` and work with objects as list and nodes who are created by same named function. This function could be replaced later with instanciable functions for more OOP styled approach.

This proposal takes a node and inset it, depending on the function, at the end of the list or at any place in the list. If no node exists in the list, it is inserted at the beginning of the linked list.

```js
function linkedList() {
    return { head: null, tail: null };
}

function node(data, next) {
    return { data, next };
}

function insertTail(list, node) {
    if (list.head) {
        list.tail.next = node;
        list.tail = list.tail.next;
    } else {
        list.head = node;
        list.tail = node;
    }
    return list;
}

function insertPos(list, node, n) {
    var temp = list.head,
        previous;

    if (!temp) {
        return insertTail(list, node);
    }

    while (temp.next && n--) {
        previous = temp;
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    node.next = temp;
    previous.next = node;

    return list;
}

var songs = [{ id: '1', name: 'Kamikaze', artist: 'Eminem', releaseDate: '2018-08-31' }, { id: '2', name: 'despacito', artist: 'Luis Fonsi', releaseDate: '2018-08-31' }, { id: '3', name: 'La tortura', artist: 'Shakira', releaseDate: '2018-08-31' }, { id: '4', name: 'Roar', artist: 'Roar', releaseDate: '2018-08-31' }],
    list = linkedList();

songs.forEach(song => insertTail(list, node(song)));
console.log(list);

insertPos(list, node({ id: '5', name: 'Havana', artist: 'who knows', releaseDate: '2018-01-01' }), 3);
console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```